# 'random' function $r_{n+1} = f(r_n)$, $|\{r_i,\forall i\}|=N$, $r_N = r_1$ where a function $g(r_k)=k$ is harder than in ECC?

Tags: random-number-generator, complexity, pseudo-random-permutation

Is there a deterministic pseudo random function $f$ with $r_{n+1} = f(r_n)$, $|\{r_i,\forall i\}|=N$, $r_N = r_0$, (for given random initial value $r_0$) where a function which derives the index of a given value $g(r_k)=k$ is harder than deriving the index of a given value at elliptic curve cryptography?

For ECC e.g. Babystep-Giantstep-Algorithmus or Pollard-Rho-Methode can be used with about $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$.

Getting the index of the random function value $r_k$ can't be harder than $\mathcal{O}({N})$ because that would be the computation of it.

So I'm looking for a complexity harder than $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$, in best case $\mathcal{O}({N})$.

---

Further nodes:

-set $R=\{r_i\forall i, \text{ given one } r_0 = r_N\}$ don't need to pass any tests for randomness

-$(\max(R)-\min(R)) <= b\cdot N$ with $b<=\sqrt[3]{N}$ and $b<=32$, $|R|=N$

-computation time of $f$ should not increase with higher index or $r$

Comment: You haven't specified any way a key figures into this, so it doesn't make sense to talk about $f$ as a pseudorandom function, but would any fixed preimage-resistant function like SHA-256 serve your needs?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage not 100% familiar with SHA-256 but with this chance is high $r_n$ is equal to any $r_k, k<n$ with $k \ll 2^{250}$ which is against requirements above (the range of numbers which are produced by $f$ should not be much higher than the value count in that range). Idea behind this is to create the same value set with a limited number of identities for each user which should not know the index of a certain number unless he computed all until it.

Comment: The average cycle length of a uniform random function of 256-bit strings is about $2^{128}$ (see [Harris 1960](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237803?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) ([paywall-free](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237803)) for details).  In practical terms, you're never going to even _find_ an element on a cycle, let alone actually cycle back to an element you've seen before.  If you insist on making this length not merely ‘not gonna happen’ but ‘completely meaningless’, you could use SHA-512 on 512-bit strings instead.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage ty for response and some new information but that's not what I'm looking for. As you wrote my wished function is not a real random function because of no duplicates allowed. But SHA-256 won't work because if cycle length is $2^{128}$  the 'random' values inside can be up to $2^{128}$ times bigger. This ratio should not be higher than about 32 (as written above). This SHA would only work if there is an efficient way to produce a random SHA value which lies in this target cycle without the knowledge of any initial value. But I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Something similar with a max value inside as big as the cycle length would work.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.  (With SHA-256, the number of values is around $N = 2^{256}$ (maybe closer to $(1 - 1/e) 2^{256}$), and $\min(R) \geq 0$ and $\max(R) < 2^{256}$, so $(\max(R) - \min(R)) \leq b\cdot N$ for $b = 1$.)  What are you hoping to do with such a beast as you have characterized once you have one?  With numbers this large, what does it matter what the exact cycle length is?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage $N$ is the cycle length for one given $r_0$ because $r_N=r_0$. So the number of values in that cycle are only $\approx 2^{128} = N$. I made some changes in top post to make more clear.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with such a thing if you find one?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I need a (small $<10^{20}$) amount of numbers which can be produced out of each other. For the initial value need to exist a random function which can be executed at user PC. The user should not know how to compute a certain value out of this initial value.

Comment: Can you expand more on the context—give more details about what you're trying to _enable users to do_, rather than saying more about the isolated specific properties you think you need of a function to serve the users?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage it's different to normal cryptography. Instead of encrypting values the connection between (small number of) known values (those which can be produced by the Independent random function for the initial value (not this I'm asking for here)) should be encrypted. Also the user acts like an attacker. But he should be able to produce a small fraction of those values but should not know how to produce a certain value. The total amount of values is limited among all user. Let's say the user get some points for each value (depending at value). Normal PC 100-10000 values per second.